# blazor how to add fake auth on serverside?/api

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

so i have some client side blazor app
it uses OIDC external auth by the 'production' version
but during development
thos oidc is slow and i did not wanted to wait 15s on every debug to auth / enter cert pin
so i have some fake `auth state provider` that pretend that user is authenticated and have some permissions

and now on serverside all controllers allow anonym
but when production then

```
 app.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
```

do the trick of prod-security .

and now i have some places where i need this OIDC/or fake username

```
 string login = User.Claims.Where(p => p.Type == "preferred_username").First().Value;
```

this works fine when PROD
bud when development and fake auth - sequence contains no elements - as i do not pass any token to request when development so expeted ;/ ...

**so question is how to fake auth on server side also ? so this userclaims is filled with some fake data during development time?**

thanks alot and regards

Comment: Whyat exactly is (fake) _auch_ ?  Is that a typo?

Comment: Ok, so what is _autch_ ?

Comment: is that all? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it like here and works fine - not sure if best option ? please feel free to comment if anyone have better idea

```
public class DebugAuthenticationHandler : 
AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
public DebugAuthenticationHandler(
  IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
  ILoggerFactory logger,
  UrlEncoder encoder,
  ISystemClock clock)
  : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) { }

protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
{
    var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "DebugAdmin") };
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
    claims.Add(new Claim("preferred_username", "DebugAdmin"))
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Server authentication");
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);
    return await Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
}
}
```

and startup:

```
 if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
 {
   builder.Services.AddAuthentication(
   options => options.AddScheme<DebugAuthenticationHandler>("debug", "debug"));
   builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("debug");
    defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I'd advice you to not do stuff differently in the development environment than in production, because bugs there tend to go unnoticed, but if you don't see any other way around it, I guess you can overwrite the default principal factory with some own implementation like this:

```cs
    public class PrincipalFactory : AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>{

       public PrincipalFactory(IAccessTokenProviderAccessor accessor) : base(accessor)
       {
       }

       public override async ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(RemoteUserAccount account, RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
       {
           var principal = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);

           if (principal.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
           {
               identity.AddClaim(new Claim("preferred_username", "dev_user"));
           } 

           return principal;
       }
    }
```

And add it in your `Program.cs`:

```
var authBuilder = builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options => { });

if(builder.Environment.IsDevelopment()){
    authBuilder.AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<PrincipalFactory>();
}
```

I did not test this, but I think you get the idea.

Edit: It just occured to me that a better way maybe would be to only add this factory in development environment, so I reworked the example a bit.

Comment: i known that this is not best option but external oidc cause like 10-15s delay on every dev test so i needed something diferent / fast. alternative would be to do own oidc on api but i do not thintk that this is worht so much effort. what would be best alternative that You think of ?  thanks for code - will try it ;)

Comment: with var authBuilder = builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options => { });
 it crashes on builder.build because Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IPostConfigureOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.OidcProviderOptions]] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.DefaultOidcOptionsConfiguration':

Comment: I guess some required configurations are missing in my example, I didn't set up a working OIDC setting :)

Comment: yes thats what i guess also but had no idea how to send 'empty working config' ;P do You have any better idea of how it should be done other / better way in cause of slow external oidc autch ? regards !

Comment: I had the impression you just have some configuration for your environment that you add there.